# CodeIgniter Calendar Preferences template not working

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, associative-array

Here is my `$prefs`.

```
   $prefs = array(
            'month_type' => 'long',
            'day_type' => 'short',
            'show_next_prev' => true,
            'next_prev_url' => base_url('calendar/index'),
            'show_other_days' => true,

        );
        $prefs['template'] = array(
            'table_open' => "<table class='calendar'>",
            'cal_cell_start' => '<td class="day">',
            'cal_cell_start_today' => '<td class="today">'
        );
```

Then here is the output when i run this code.

```
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($prefs);
 echo '</pre>';die();


Array
(
    [month_type] => long
    [day_type] => short
    [show_next_prev] => 1
    [next_prev_url] => http://localhost/MeemoStore/calendar/index
    [show_other_days] => 1
    [template] => Array
        (
            [table_open] => 
            [cal_cell_start] => 
[cal_cell_start_today] =>   ) )
```

I've configured a calendar before and i had no problem with it. Can anyone help me out?

[EDIT]

```
  $this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);
  echo $this->calendar->generate($year, $month); die();
```

OUTPUT HTML:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">

<tr>
<th colspan="7">October&nbsp;2016</th>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>Su</td><td>Mo</td><td>Tu</td><td>We</td><td>Th</td><td>Fr</td><td>Sa</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td><td>21</td><td>22</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>23</td><td><strong>24</strong></td><td>25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td><td>28</td><td>29</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>30</td><td>31</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

The template didn't affect the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calendar library was on autoload file, i removed it from there and it is now working. Sorry for the post!

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue in your array.

Your `html` tags are getting parsed by browser.

Try `var_dump`

```
var_dump($prefs);
```

Or set `Content-Type: plain/text` in header

Comment: I can see the length on var_dump but its not working on my calendar. Will edit the post to show the output.

Comment: your code works for me.. I think the issue in some other part.

Comment: CodeIgniter 3, the latest version.